# Use nested *ngFor for generating table from an array of object and an array of key strings

Tags: angular, nested-loops, ngfor

I've an array of objects (data) and an array of strings (attributes). The attributes array holds keys for the object I'm interested in. I want to use it in the template to generate a table.

```
<div class="row-wrapper" *ngFor="let da of data">
    <div class="ls-row">
        <div class="row dis-flex">
            <template ngFor let-attr [ngForOf]="attributes">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <div class="ls-row-text small-text">
                    {{da.attr}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Rajiv glad to hear that you have solved your problem. plz don't forget to  upvote if my answer helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

This: `{{ da[attr] }}` is the key.

Answer (score 2):

i think you want to extract all data for keys which are stored in some other array.

```
  <div class="row-wrapper" *ngFor="let attr of attributes">
        <div class="ls-row">
            <div class="row dis-flex">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div class="ls-row-text small-text">
                           {{data[attr]}}
                        </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i hope this will help